# Connect to Wifi using Flutter

Tags: flutter, wifi, wpa

I'm working on a Flutter project that needs to connect to a certain wifi by entering username and password.

I'm using wifi_configuration package which I can connect to a wifi by entering the SSID and password.

Is there any other way to connect to wifi using username and password in Flutter?

Comment: It's a very open question that can be answered in many ways. If you can precise more what you want and why, then it might lead to a better answer.

Comment: I want to connect to a wifi wpa2 enterprise from flutter app, I'm searching for a library for that but I didn't found any useful one.

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to wifi requires signing-in through a webpage from the browser, then it's not possible to be done through Flutter. Plugins available can only connect you through the SSID with a password. Aside from `wifi_configuration`, there are other options like [wifi_connect](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_connect) plugin.

```dart
await WifiConnect.connect(
  context,
  ssid: ssidControl.text,
  password: passwordControl.text,
  hidden: hidden,
  securityType: hidden ? SecurityType.wpa : SecurityType.auto,
);
```

Where `ssidControl` and `passwordControl` can be set on TextField widgets to configure the wifi password.

```dart
TextField(
  controller: ssidControl,
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'SSID'),
),
TextField(
  controller: passwordControl,
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
),
```

Comment: This plugin no longer works with Dart 3. Any other similar plugins now?

Comment: You can check [wifi_connector](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_connector) plugin